# 500 -Internal error on web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-7.5

I just recently switched from shared hosting to a vps on GoDaddy.  I had a webservice that worked just fine on the shared hosting.  I am trying to get it working under my vps.  I continually get a 500 - internal error when going to the link.

I did set it up as a application in IIS, and i made its own application pool using integrated pipes.

Any ideas on what else may be causing this issue?

EDIT 1:
If i switch my application pool over to use the same application pool as my site, i get this error instead:
"Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The page must have a <%@ webservice class="MyNamespace.MyClass" ... %> directive.

Source Error:

Line 1:  This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!

Source File: /webservices/namesearch.asmx    Line: 1 "

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>


 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<!--
  The <authentication> section enables configuration 
  of the security authentication mode used by 
  ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
-->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>

      <!--
       The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
       of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
       during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
       it enables developers to configure html error pages 
       to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

       <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
         <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
         <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
       </customErrors>
    -->
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
</configuration>
```

EDIT 2:
So i noticed on that parser error it was also saying "Source Error:

Line 1:  This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!"

so i tried to do a precompile on the webservice.  When i do this i get the error saying "It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='machinetoapplication' beyond application level. this error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in iis"

Comment: Did you look for/in the log files...?

Comment: Which 500 did you actually get? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891

Comment: The only thing i have seen are these two logs "The WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service service entered the running state." and "A worker process with process id of '2672' serving application pool 'Webservices' was shutdown due to inactivity.  Application Pool timeout configuration was set to 5 minutes.  A new worker process will be started when needed."

Comment: This is the full description of my 500 "500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

Comment: is old shared hostings IIS were also iis 7.5? Which version of IIS was it?

Comment: http://www.politicprofiles.com/webservices/namesearch.asmx

Comment: @AndyXufuris I mean, is Old server was also IIS 7.5? Because is this webservice uses some old components on IIS 7.5 you need to pus some handlers for them.

Comment: any chance you can check eventLogs at eventviewer?

Comment: I already checked the event logs and there is nothing there.  I think the old server may have been IIS 7.0 but i can't remember.  It was not below 7.0 though.

Comment: any chance that namesearch.asmx is corrupted? it has to be a single line like `<%@ WebService Language="cs" Codebehind="namesearch.asmx.cs" Class="MyNamespace.MyClass" %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used [SoapClient](http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html) to hit [your web service](http://www.politicprofiles.com/webservices/namesearch.asmx). It allows us to quickly [supply arguments to your web service](http://www.soapclient.com/soapclient?template=/clientform.html&fn=soapform&SoapTemplate=/SoapResult.html&SoapWSDL=http://www.politicprofiles.com/webservices/namesearch.asmx?WSDL&_ArraySize=2).

Suspect that your error is on `NameSearch.asmx.cs:line 29` where you're likely trying to write or read the Event Log (specifically the Security log). Likely `EventLog.WriteEntry()`.

The issue here is that, behind the scenes, your call is trying to `VerifyAndCreateSource()` without having proper authorization.

To solve this, grant the appropriate permissions to the Security Event Log. Likely the user context running is under NetworkService.

Consider implementing the steps in [IIS7: Web Application writing to Event Log generates Security Exception](http://www.christiano.ch/wordpress/2009/12/02/iis7-web-application-writing-to-event-log-generates-security-exception/). The main idea here is to allow Network Service, or whatever security context your app is running under, permission to write to the registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog
```

[image]

The full error thrown in your .NET code is:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. To create the source, you need permission to read all event logs to make sure that the new source name is unique. Inaccessible logs: Security. at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.FindSourceRegistration(String source, String machineName, Boolean readOnly, Boolean wantToCreate) at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.SourceExists(String source, String machineName, Boolean wantToCreate) at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.VerifyAndCreateSource(String sourceName, String currentMachineName) at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[] rawData) at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String message) at WebServices.NameSearch.GetSearchResult(String prefixText, Int32 count) in C:\Users\xufurisa\Dropbox\Programs\PoliticProfiles\WebServices\NameSearch.asmx.cs:line 29

Comment: Thank you so much.  This greatly helped.  After removing that and changing a couple things in my web config, it started working.  That soap web client was a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

To determine where in your code your errors is occurring, edit your web.config to include:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: This did not do anything different for me

Comment: Are you sure there is 1 customerrors section in your web.config and it is Off. And can you post your web.config?